# Spinnaker Installation via helm in terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, spinnaker

I am trying to install spinnaker on Kubernetes with Terraform using the following resource:

```
resource "helm_release" "spinnaker" {
  chart      = "stable/spinnaker"
  name       = "spinnaker"
  repository = "https://helmcharts.opsmx.com/"
  version    = "2.2.3"
```

I keep on receiving the following error message:

```
Error: chart "stable/spinnaker" version "2.2.3" not found in https://helmcharts.opsmx.com/ repository
  on spinnaker-helm/helm.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "spinnaker":
   1: resource "helm_release" "spinnaker" {
```

Here is the artifact hub chart we try to refer to:

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/spinnaker/spinnaker

I am using terraform 0.14 and helm provider 1.2.3

Thank you for your help.

Charles

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as the correct one if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is "spinnaker/spinnaker" and not "stable/spinnaker".

In general stable repo was deprecated and wiped on Nov 2020.

Those are the available charts in the repot you are adding:

```
 ebiriukov@Evgenis-MacBook-Pro ➜  ~ helm search repo spinnaker                                                                                                      <aws:iris-dev>
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /Users/ebiriukov/.kube/config
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /Users/ebiriukov/.kube/config
NAME                        CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
spinnaker/spinnaker         2.2.3           1.22.2      Open source, multi-cloud continuous delivery pl...
spinnaker/oes               3.4.0           3.4.0       OES is a non-forked version of OSS spinnaker
spinnaker/opsmx-autopilot   2.0.0           2.9.10      Autopilot is a release verification platform
```